# $A$ and $\phi(A)$ are of the same category.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, $\phi : X \to X$ a homeomorphism, and
$A \subset X$. Prove that $A$ and $\phi(A)$ are of the same category.

Let $A$ be a set of first category. Then $A$ can be expressed as a countable union of nowhere dense sets. I have also proved that homeomorphic image of a nowhere dense set is nowhere dense. So the image of $A$ i.e. $\phi(A)$ can be written as a countable union of no where dense sets. Hence $\phi(A)$ is also a set of 1st category.

A set is of second category if it is not of 1st category. How can we conclude from here that homeomorphic image of the set will also be of second category.

Anyone can give some hints to the problem?

Comment: Do we mean "category" here in the sense of Baire categories, i.e. meager or co-meager?

Comment: same as 1st and 2nd category

Comment: You may wanna clarify that just a little at the start, as "category" can have many meanings. But what you wanna show here is that $\phi(A)$ is first category *if and only if* $A$ is. This could be done one of two ways: either (a) show that if $A$ is second category, then so is $\phi(A)$, or (b) show that if $\phi(A)$ is of first category, then so is $A$. The latter seems more reliable.

Comment: I have done the latter ....is my method correct?

Comment: You have stated the former and proven neither.

Comment: Let AA be a set of first category. Then AA can be expressed as a countable union of nowhere dense sets. I have also proved that homeomorphic image of a nowhere dense set is nowhere dense. So the image of AA i.e. ϕ(A)ϕ(A) can be written as a countable union of no where dense sets. Hence ϕ(A)ϕ(A) is also a set of 1st category.

Comment: Yes, that's showing if $A$ is of first category (or meager), then so is $\phi (A)$. What you now need to show is the converse. Perhaps there's a $B$ that isn't meager (i.e. of second category), but $\phi(B)$ is meager (i.e. of first category). This you have not addressed.